# Python append to JSON formatted string

Tags: python, json

I have a json formatted string like:

```
jsonObj = json.dumps({'name': str(dsetName)})
```

I am trying to append to this string by doing the following, but it gives me an error:

```
jsonObj += json.dumps({'base': baseds})
```

Eventually I want to end up with the output of

`json.dumps({'name': str(dsetName), 'base': baseds})`

after appending. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *What* error is it giving you…?

Comment: I think you can't create correctly formated JSON using concatenation.

Comment: Also, the best you'll end up with this way is `{"name": "foo"}{"base": "bar"}`. You must construct your desired object *before* you `json.dumps` it; you can't really work with your data when it's encoded as a JSON *string*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep track of the object itself (by building it up first) and then perform the `json.dump` on the object when it's time to pass it off as a string.

Due to the nature of JSON, you must have one open and one closing brace (`{}`) to signify a single object. If you append dumps, the result would look like:

> {'name': dsetName}{'base': baseds}

Which is not valid JSON.